# Loop through rows and store cell values as variables to run fomrulas, end result in another cell

Tags: vba, excel, loops, variables

[image: excel]
I'd like to scan each row and pull out certain cells and store them as variables. When I get to the end of the row, I want to run a series of formulas and vlookups. I have the formulas and vlookups all set up, but I need to scan each line and then take the result of the those formulas and put them back in another cell. Here's come example code

```
Dim height As Double
Dim weight As Double
Dim gender As String
Dim newWeight as Double

'I'd like to set the loop here
'for each row do this
height = d2.value
weight = f2.value
gender = k2.value

'then run through my equations
If gender = "F" and weight < 20 Then
 newWeight = weight + 5
ElseIf gender = "F" and weight > 20 Then
 newWeight = weight -2
End If

l2.value = newWeight.value
'Then clear variables and run through the new row
```

My equations are a little more complex then that, but I think that will get me started.

**EDIT: Do I need to reference what sheet I'm using? I bet I do

Comment: In your code `d2` does not mean "cell D2" it means the variable (object probably) called `d2`.  You probably want to change that (and all the other similar things) to `Range("D2")` or `Cells(2, "D")`.  If you use the `Cells` way of referencing things, it will be easy to do a `For` loop (e.g. `For rowNum = 2 To 20`) and use `Cells(rowNum, "D")` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for that info, my VBA experience has only been with forms and not working directly with work sheets

Comment: By default, the `ActiveSheet` is used as the sheet to which all range and cell objects are referring.  So as long as your code is simply being run when the sheet is active, you shouldn't be getting an errors from that.  But if there is a chance that this sheet won't be active when the macro is run, change all the `Range...` bits to `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range...` (obviously using whatever sheet name is appropriate.)

Comment: ... and `Rows.Count` to `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count` (and again,  obviously using whatever sheet name is appropriate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to mess with your code , but this should do what you need,

```
Dim height As Double
Dim weight As Double
Dim gender As String
Dim newWeight As Double
Dim lastrow As Long

 lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

 For i = 2 To lastrow
    'I'd like to set the loop here
    'for each row do this
    height = CDbl(Range("D" & i).value)
    weight = CDbl(Range("F" & i).value)
    gender = Range("K" & i).value

    'then run through my equations
    If gender = "F" And weight < 20 Then
     newWeight = weight + 5
    ElseIf gender = "F" And weight > 20 Then
     newWeight = weight - 2
    End If

    Range("I" & i).value = newWeight
    'Then clear variables and run through the new row
    newWeight = 0
    height = 0
    weight = 0
    gender = 0
 Next
```

Comment: I suggest you start the loop at `2`, because row 1 is headings (and set lastRow based on one of the columns the OP has populated)

Comment: @YowE3K, I didn't even look at the table. I am guessing the OP will be able to figure that out,but....

Comment: @YowE3K, very true.

Comment: my apologies for omitting row numbers. I have a couple columns that I don't need for the variables and I cropped them out.

Comment: Also getting type mismatch, I'm sure that's an operator (me) issue

Comment: the value of i is 2

Comment: @mcadamsjustin, what Yow said. what is the value of `i` and the value of the same row you are getting data from

Comment: @mcadamsjustin, is the cell format as no string types?

Comment: @KyloRen - I'll bow out of this discussion, and leave it up to you to resolve :D

Comment: I thought of that and double checked, it's formatted as a number with 2 decimal places

Comment: @KyloRen sadly it's the same error, even tried just the general number formatting

Comment: SO, I closed Excel and reopend, and it works. I have no answers for that, but thanks for all your help

Comment: @mcadamsjustin, no worries, glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: @mcadamsjustin, Up Vote for the effort in getting this solved. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

See below code

```
Sub temp()

    Dim height As Double
    Dim weight As Double
    Dim gender As String
    Dim newWeight As Double

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        'I'd like to set the loop here
        'for each row do this
        height = Range("D" & i).Value
        weight = Range("F" & i).Value
        gender = Range("K" & i).Value

        'then run through my equations
        If gender = "F" Then
            If weight < 20 Then
                newWeight = weight + 5
            ElseIf weight > 20 Then
                newWeight = weight - 2
            End If
        End If

        Range("L" & i).Value = newWeight
        'Then clear variables and run through the new row
    Next i

End Sub
```

You also need to figure out what will happen if weight = 20 :P

Comment: I suggest you change `lastRow` to be a `Long`.  +1 for the comment about weight=20 giving problems.

Comment: I'm getting a type mismatch error for height = Range("D" & i).Value. Also the weight being greater or less than 20 was an example, but good point, you'd definitely want to use an equal too operator in there some where

Comment: I don't see a reason for the type mismatch unless you are having the data as string in the cells. try to manually enter a number for height and run the code in debug mode

Comment: I thought of that and double checked, it's formatted as a number with 2 decimal places

Comment: Is there a formula in Column E (Height Rounded). Why don't you use this column for the height just to see if the code works. Change `Range("D" & i).Value` to `Range("E" & i).Value`

Comment: SO, I closed Excel and reopend, and it works. I have no answers for that, but thanks for all your help. I marked @kyloren's as the answer because he was a little more patient, but yours also works, thanks!!

Comment: Great! Cheers. ;)